# maven creates corrupted repository folders

Tags: maven

Why maven creates this wrong folders? What kind of problem can generate this behaviour? I'm using artifactory to manage jars.

```
1.0/
1.0.1/
1.0.2/
1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/
1.0.3/
1.0.3-/
1.0.3-S/
1.0.3-SN/
1.0.3-SNA/
1.0.3-SNAP/
1.0.3-SNAPS/
1.0.3-SNAPSH/
1.0.3-SNAPSHO/
1.0.3-SNAPSHOT/
maven-metadata-local.xml*
maven-metadata-repo.xml*
maven-metadata-repo.xml.sha1*
resolver-status.properties*
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Why maven creates this wrong folders? ` ? Maven creates those based on the information in the pom files like groupId, artifactId and version? So I would check the pom files...

Comment: The poms are right and doesn't change. Sometimes, I suppose for network problems, the repository became corrupted. The various directories S, SN, SNA, SNAP etc are spurious.
In that case I've to delete spurious folders manually